# Final Variable Until Next Iteration Python?

Tags: python

I am coding a for loop in which I have a preassigned boolean named flag. In one particular case during this loop I need to keep flag as True (final) despite if I try to change it later to False. After I complete an iteration of this loop and return to the top, I would like my flag variable to become "changeable" once again. I was originally trying to use `continue` but it seemed inefficient. Are there any better ways to achieve this?

```py
import random

border = []
numline = []
size = 100  
for i in range (size):   
    numline.append(round(i + 1 * random.random(), 2))     
flag = True
total = 0
previous = total
avDif = (numline[size - 1] - numline[0] / (size - 1))
for i in range (1, size):     
    total += numline[i] - numline[i - 1]   
    if total >= avDif:    
        if avDif - previous >= total - avDif or flag:                
            border.append(numline[i]) 
            total = 0   
            previous = total   
            continue  
        else:   
            total = numline[i] - numline[i - 1]             
            border.append(numline[i - 1])            
    previous = total  
    flag = False
```

Comment: Please show some code to go along with your verbal description.

Comment: "In one particular case during this loop I need to keep flag as True (final) despite if I try to change it later to False" - why not just *not* try to set it to `False` in that case?

Comment: Because the statement in which I need to keep flag true needs the flag to be true in the first place

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: "Because the statement in which I need to keep flag true needs the flag to be true in the first place" - Yeah, and if you don't try to set the flag to `False`, the flag will be `True`, so everything's fine.

Comment: Why do you need `flag` at all? What does it represent? What is it's purpose?

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a ton : ) The goal in this program is me taking differences between randomly generated points and combining them to be around the size of the average difference between all the points. Flag helps say even if the difference between the current difference and the average is ginormously larger than the difference between the average difference and the previous if we just started a new group we have to include it.

Comment: You're right tho! I will try to figure out a way to add that difference without using flag when I create a new range :) Thank you so so so much. I'm new to the Stack Overflow platform so everything helps!